strategy to file multiple provisional applications for the same patent
I've got two related patents that I need to apply for.
One is being drafted right now by an attorney, and it's taking much longer than initially estimated.
I've also learned a lot about patents from working with the attorney and reading their work.
For the second patent, I cannot afford for it to take this long (only to draft a provisional).
So my strategy is to use the format and boilerplate wording of the provisional application of the first patent to draft my own provisional application for the second patent.
I then plan to submit this second provisional on my own without any revision.
I then plan to have the attorney review and revise my drafted provisional. If any revisions are made, then I'll file a second provisional application on the same invention.
When it comes time to file the non-provisional, I'll first attempt to base it on the second, revised, provisional application. If somehow, prior art was added between the first and second application that renders the second application obvious, then I"ll fall back to the first provisional application.
See anything that could backfire with this strategy?

If the subject matter of the two inventions are closely related a version of this plan  could be a reasonable approach. You will need to file a non-provisional application within one year of the first provisional. In it you can claim priority from both.
If you get a rejection based upon a reference dated between the two provisional’s filing dates you hope to have sufficient support in the first one to save the rejected claim or claims.
If your plan was to decide to claim the benefit of only one of the provisionals based on a search you perform, it’s a bad plan. Even if it was a professional search it can’t find unpublished patent applications.

If I understand the strategy correctly, you plan to make a search to determine whether there is intervening relevant prior art and only then revert to the first application.
One obvious shortcoming of this strategy is that there can be prior art that is intervening but you failed to find it (or it is even part of an unpublished application at that time). In that case you will choose to base on the second provisional which won't work in your favor.
Aside: It shouldn't take that long to get one round of review from a patent practitioner. If it turns out the draft is in such poor shape that more rounds are necessary, would it even have been worth to file the initial draft? A provisional is only good for anything if it can support claims. I recommend to skip filing anything that is half-baked where there are doubts that it can support claims later on.
At any rate, if you must go it alone, do at least read "Patent It Yourself" from cover to cover.

Note that the OP does need to search and hope, they can claim the benefit of both in any non-provisional filed within the year after the first one. I agree that they need to learn as much as they can and the book is a great resource.

@GeorgeWhite Well, claiming from both is a possibility but it is not OP's described strategy which they were asking about. Also, I am skeptical about the wisdom of having multiple provisionals that are merely restatements of the same invention. It seems to create additional room for varied interpretations that may not be what patentee intended. Usually follow-up provisionals are filed if there are further developments and refinements of the base invention that need to be described to support additional claims.

I edited my answer. You are correct that the OP may have thought to only claim the benefit of one of them which would be a bad plan.
